# datepicker limit current year

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I have a little problem with datepicker, I'd want that a user with arrows can only select a date between the first day of the first month and the last day of the month, but it would be dynamic because if we are in 2014 I have to see only year of 2014.

I have tried in this mode but with arrows I can go to 2012 or 2014 for example:

```
$('#check-in').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm', changeYear: false, yearRange: "-0:+0", stepYears: 0  });
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Set `minDate` and `maxDate` like

```
$(function() {
    var year = (new Date).getFullYear();
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
        minDate: new Date(year, 0, 1),
        maxDate: new Date(year, 11, 31)
    });
});
```

[Link](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#min-max)

Comment: yes works a little bit, if I click on the arrow at the top to change month I can go into 2014 for example but if I click it set me 2013, the better solution is that I can't see 2014 or other year, only the current year

Answer (score 2):

Just use `yearRange` like this:

```
datepick({yearRange: new Date().getFullYear() + ':' + new Date().getFullYear()});
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not mention the yearRange to be currentyear : currentyear?

You can do this:
after

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var curyear = $("#year").text( (new Date).getFullYear() );
```

Inside your datepicker,
    `yearRange: "+curyear+":"+curyear+"`

Comment: error again SyntaxError: missing } after property list pointed on: of   "+curyear+":"+curyear+"

Answer (score 0):

This will work for you:

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SMjcb/1/)

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
  <script>

    $(document).ready(function() {

        var date = new Date(), y = date.getFullYear(), m = date.getMonth();
        var fSDate = new Date(y, m, 1);
        var fEDate = new Date(y, m + 1, 0);

        $.datepicker.setDefaults({
            changeMonth: false,
            changeYear: false,
            showOtherMonths: false,
            yearRange: '-0:+0',
            dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
            defaultDate: +0,
            numberOfMonths: 1,
            minDate: fSDate, 
            maxDate: fEDate,
            showAnim: 'fadeIn',
            showButtonPanel: false
        });

        $('#date_start').datepicker();

    }); //END document.ready()
  </script>
</head>
<body>

    <input type="text" id="date_start">

</body>
</html>
```